# Why do I have to restart server on every style change?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, next.js, css-purge

I'm working on a NextJS application with PurgeCSS. I have to restart the server every single time I change the classname of a component.

Here are my `postcss.config.js`:

```
  plugins: [
    [
      '@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss',
      {
        content: [
          './src/pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
          './src/pages/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
          './src/components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
          './src/containers/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
        ],
        defaultExtractor: (content) => content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || [],
        safelist: ['html', 'body'],
        enableDevPurge: false,
      },
    ],
    'postcss-preset-env',
  ],
};
```

My `package.json` dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "next": "13.1.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "sass": "^1.57.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/node": "18.11.18",
    "@types/react": "18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.48.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.48.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "eslint": "8.31.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-next": "^0.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.11",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "lint-staged": "13.1.0",
    "next-purge-css-modules": "1.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.20",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^5.0.2",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^7.8.3",
    "prettier": "^2.8.1",
    "typescript": "4.9.4"
  }
```

I'm using global styles, not module styles, and scss instead of css.

This is my `_app.tsx`:

```
import '../styles/Global.scss';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```

Say I have these two styles:

```
.bg-blue { background-color: blue; }
.bg-red { background-color: red; }
```

If I had `bg-blue` used on a `div`'s `className`, and I change it to `bg-red`, its ruleset is missing from the stylesheet.

I'm assuming purgecss doesn't update the stylesheet and does only one purge on server start.

It's definitely not ideal, but I don't care if I can just disable the whole purge functionality. However, can't find a way for that either.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps anyone who is here looking for a solution to Next.js and PostCSS related issues.

I had a similar problem using Next.js 14, Panda-CSS, and PostCSS. I fixed it by writing a special script for development. This script checks for any changes in my `.ts` and `.tsx` files. When it finds a change, it makes a small update to my `globals.css` file (in your case, it will be `styles/Global.scss`).

This small change tells Next.js that the styles have changed. Next.js then creates new CSS based on these changes. This solution worked well for me and kept my styles updated.

```
const chokidar = require("chokidar");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const cssFilePath = path.join(
  __dirname,
  "../../packages/app/src/app/globals.css"
);

function updateCssCounter() {
  let content = fs.readFileSync(cssFilePath, "utf8");
  let match = content.match(/\/\*\s*(\d+)\s*\*\//);
  let counter = match ? parseInt(match[1]) + 1 : 1;

  if (match) {
    content = content.replace(/\/\*\s*\d+\s*\*\//, `/* ${counter} */`);
  } else {
    content += `\n/* ${counter} */`;
  }

  fs.writeFileSync(cssFilePath, content, "utf8");
}

const watcher = chokidar.watch(
  [
    "../../packages/app/src/**/*.ts",
    "../../packages/app/src/**/*.tsx",
    "../../packages/design-system/src/**/*.ts",
    "../../packages/design-system/src/**/*.tsx",
  ],
  {
    ignored: /node_modules/,
    persistent: true,
  }
);

watcher.on("change", (path) => {
  console.log(`CHANGED: ${path}`);
  updateCssCounter();
});

console.log("Watching for file changes...");
```